# Why memory is not released even I delete a 6GB postgres table

Tags: database, postgresql, memory-management

I have deleted around ten thousand records of an Attachment Table, where the files are attached as a BLOB type. Before deleting those files, I had 17.4 GB memory in C:// drive. I as expecting 6 GB Memory to be released once the delete has been executed.

But The memory has not released. What may be the reason.

Comment: I had understood the size of the Table using the query from here https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Disk_Usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't free disk space immediately after deleting rows from a table. You can use the [`VACUUM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-vacuum.html) command to do that. Note that there is an auto-vacuum process, so the disk space would probably be freed up eventually.

Comment: Ok. Let me try. But what you mean by eventually.

Comment: The release of  memory will happen over a period of time?

Comment: Yes, but it depends on many conditions and it will still leave some unused space allocated. If you want to restore the table to the minimum disk space, you need to use `VACUUM FULL` (which will temporarily use twice the disk space).

Comment: @Sajeev: eventually means that if you wait long enough the diskspace will be freed automatically.

Comment: I have executed "vacuum verbose" on my database. I got a long log on the console. But only 100MB memory has released!

Comment: And the log says as follows at the end.:    

ERROR:  out of memory
DETAIL:  Failed on request of size 1073741820.

********** Error **********

ERROR: out of memory
SQL state: 53200
Detail: Failed on request of size 1073741820.

Comment: My database size is around 18 GB and 17.4 GB is available(free) in the Disk. Do I need more memory to perform this action?

Comment: I have run VACUUM FULL. And it as successfull. It have released around 6 GB. Thank you @LukášLalinský

Comment: It's important to understand the VACUUM does NOT release memory to the OS. It only marks spaces occupied by the deleted rows as FREE to get used by Postgres.